# Is Certificates are required for STARTTLS connection on LDAP

Tags: server, ssl, pam, ldap, tls

My LDAP server's ldap.conf file

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=coretesting,dc=com
URI     ldap://ldap.coretesting.com #ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/ssl/certs/
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem    
TLS_CERT /etc/ssl/certs/slapd01.pem
TLS_KEY /etc/ssl/private/slapd01_key.pem
#TLS_CRLCHECK all
#TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN 3
```

Whenever my client tries to connect with the server first time alone ldap_start_tls_s fails.

Error code ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)

The second time onwards it is working fine.

I know that TLS_REQCERT demand data on ldap.conf file can resolve this error.

When we try to use a secured connection there is no meaning of providing other than demand option.

If any experts know the root cause or solution please let me know.

Regards,
Ram